# What IP to use for self-testing?

Tags: local-area-network

A bunch of servers offer functionality on a particular port (the port listens on all interfaces).  Servers must self-test their own functionality by connecting to themselves. What DNS name or IP should the test connection use?

Ideally, I'd use one of the local IPs and be done with it (e.g. '192.13.1.5'). However, obtaining the list of local IPs is difficult for the test code.

I can use 'localhost' (127.0.0.1), but this uses the loopback interface and bypasses network hardware. Which leads me to...

**Question:** Is there shorthand notation for *"Any local IP this server uses"*? (except loopback address).

Using '0.0.0.0' seems to work on Linux, but not on Windows.

Comment: How about the computer's own name?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 does mean "all IPv4 addresses belonging to this machine", so you've got it right with Linux. I am unsure, but at a guess, knowing Windows there is probably a flag not set on a socket that should be, or something ridiculous like that.

Comment: Michael: I was hoping for the notation-based solution Shane pointed out. I ended up writing code to resolve.

Comment: @Shane: `0.0.0.0` indeed means that, but only in contexts where it makes sense to talk about that collection. In particular, that makes sense when accepting new TCP connections or listening for UDP packets. Not for sending data.

Comment: @MSalters sure, however is this not more of a connection question than a sending data question? :)

Comment: @Shane: That's pretty much the same. "Connecting" starts by sending a `SYN` packet.

Comment: @MSalters I think we've been looking at slightly different sides of it. I've been looking more at a listening for a connection perspective. Although yes, I do agree with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks folks - deeply appreciate your help here. Yes, hostname environment variables would work but require code to access. I'm with Shane - 0.0.0.0 *should* work, but there's something tricky about it.

I figured I'd need to create code (which had to be Java) so I wrote this to obtain three sets of IPs:

```
    List<String> IPAddress = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> NonLoopbackIPv4Address = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> NonLoopbackIPv6Address = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while(en.hasMoreElements()){
            NetworkInterface ni=(NetworkInterface) en.nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> ea = ni.getInetAddresses();
            while(ea.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress ia= (InetAddress) ea.nextElement();

                //Add entries to the overall address array 
                IPAddress.add(ia.getHostAddress());

                //Add entries to non-loopback IPv4 address array
                if (!ia.isLoopbackAddress() && (ia.getClass() == Inet4Address.class))  {
                    NonLoopbackIPv4Address.add(ia.getHostAddress());
                }

                //Add entries to non-loopback IPv6 address array
                if (!ia.isLoopbackAddress() && (ia.getClass() == Inet6Address.class))  {
                    NonLoopbackIPv6Address.add(ia.getHostAddress());
                }
            }
         }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //catch and process necessary exceptions, etc...
        throw new Exception (e);
    }
```

...where:

- IPAddress - list of all IP addresses for this host (both v4
  and v6), including those bound to the loopback interface
- NonLoopbackIPv4Address - list of all IPv4 addresses for this
  host, excluding those bound to the loopback interface
- NonLoopbackIPv6Address - list of all IPv6 addresses for this
  host, excluding those bound to the loopback interface

Comment: Was this meant to be an answer to the question? It looks like Java code. Are you on the right site? We generally don't write Java code..

Comment: Yes, its my answer to my own question. I have to write code in Java instead of shell and so decided to share it. Feel free to delete if it improves this site.

Comment: I think this question may have been more appropriate on Stack Overflow rather than Server Fault, just fyi :)

Answer (score 7):

To add to Michael Hampton's suggestion, Windows should recognize `%computername%` as an environment variable, which you can ping, etc.

It looks to me like the PowerShell cmdlet `Test-NetConnection` along with the windows environment variable might do what you want.  You can specify a port, but since you didn't mention one I just used

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME
```

and that worked fine on my laptop.  The port syntax for checking port 135 (as a random example) would be

```
Test-NetConnection -Port 135 -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME
```

Comment: Thanks Katherine. I was hoping for a notation-based, code-free solution (my test application needs code to access environment variables). I ended up biting the bullet and writing code.